# Getting different count on different timefields

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, timelion

I have data about bookings. The data has been pulled from different tables from postgresql. And I have pushed them all under the same index and type.

Now I have 6 timefields in a document.

- booking_time
- booking_update_time
- booking_end_time
- booking_rating_time
- user_date_joined
- user_last_activity

Here is the plotting of the following timelion expression,

```
.es(index='vogo-database-3', timefield='user_date_joined'), .es(index='vogo-database-3', timefield='booking_time')
```

[image]

The plotting is different when using different timefield.

My question is why is this happening ?

Every document is having a booking_time and user_date_joined. The booking_time is never the same for 2 bookings, but user_date_joined can be repeated if same user makes booking over and over again. But Then again, shouldn't the plotting be the same if every document has both fields ? IF no , why no then?

Comment: Please explain again what the different between booking_time and user_date_joined. And what each document present?